# Weiszfeld's algorithm -- incorrect answer despite perfect guess

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

I'm trying to implement Weiszfeld's algorithm to find the geometric median of a set of points. Below is what I've come up with, but gives the incorrect answer of

```
[
  0,
  0,
  12
]
```

For this test case:

```
[
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 12]
]
```

The answer should be `[0,0,0]`. The initial "guess" (computed by `findClosest(points, findMean(points))`) is actually correct, but then Weiszfeld's algorithm goes and messes it up. Seems to want to <del>converge</del> on `[0,0,12]` but that would be wrong. The distance between `[0,0,12]` and the other 2 points is 24, whereas if it had picked one of the 0 points the total distance would been 12.

How can I fix this to give more accurate results?

```js
function calcSquareDist(a, b) {
  return a.reduce((prev, curr, idx) => prev + (curr - b[idx]) ** 2, 0);
}

function calcDist(a, b) {
  return Math.sqrt(calcSquareDist(a, b));
}

function findClosest(points, target) {
  let min = {
    index: -1,
    value: Infinity
  };
  for (const [i, c] of points.entries()) {
    const d = calcSquareDist(c, target);
    if (d < min.value) {
      min = {
        index: i,
        value: d
      };
    }
  }
  return points[min.index];
}

function weightedAverage(points, w) {
  let n = points.length;
  let weightedSum = Array(points[0].length).fill(0); // initialize a vector of zeroes
  let weightSum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < points[i].length; j++) {
      weightedSum[j] += w[i] * points[i][j]; // add the weighted point to the weighted sum
    }
    weightSum += w[i]; // add the weight to the weight sum
  }
  return weightedSum.map((sum) => sum / weightSum); // return the weighted average
}
const EPSILON = 1e-6;

function findMean(points) {
  if (!(points === null || points === void 0 ? void 0 : points.length))
    throw new Error("points is empty");
  let sum = Array(points[0].length).fill(0);
  for (const p of points) {
    for (const [i, v] of p.entries()) {
      sum[i] += v;
    }
  }
  return sum.map(v => v / points.length);
}

function geometricMedian(points) {
  if (!(points === null || points === void 0 ? void 0 : points.length))
    throw new Error("points is empty");
  if (points.length === 1) {
    return points[0];
  }
  let x = findClosest(points, findMean(points));
  for (let i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
    const weights = points.map(p => calcDist(p, x));
    const x_new = weightedAverage(points, weights);
    if (calcDist(x, x_new) < EPSILON) {
      return x_new;
    }
    x = x_new;
  }
  return x;
}


console.log(geometricMedian([
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 12]
]))
```

I transpiled the above from TypeScript so that it can executed on StackOverflow. Here's [the original code on TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gSwHbCgXikgrgWwEYQBOA2gLoCwAUFQGZZIDGwCcSUDAhgDYMDKAjlg6EIAEQQBnYAAoOALliIUAGih4F8ZMACUC7PiJQA3lShmoI4FkJsOAOhEATLAwjTpYEQDdlDa4WUERwAPbXQAPihPCC8oAGooaT9CQgBaPGIg4NJtACpcgCZVAAZtKgBfKlp6JhY2Th5xKVkNJWBVdUUtXUxcAkJjU3NLazYAWQ5gAAs7CX5CGQa+QWExSRkOZTxtMspK6ko6RmZWKBpkRwBhLjgJCGawNolWrTJVYGEAcwhgF5QwkyUcxQLg-KA4ZDoYwXCDBBSpACMqi83CwEAUAEkkOckAhQPshmYaHBCElWFIoJlVAxSFA4DQok87BAUIQEPdpDtBkDgeYGOTUI4oUsBEIRE1Fu8vj9drzzAgaNIhQAecHIOworhogGEuXmCFsDBGGFwqAIZGo9FQRz7PVQW3mAk8swjGyMrQSYgGuwmih7KqHGonNgAdwgCE+U2AEEcAEEvEQON8PE89H0iGQ3lAQ2mDCQclBc-0yNzgaDUIb3SgJHZQUhPtMANy68vZ8OR6OOXi4KGxlIcEApj3EYqkWsshtTbR2c5cLjSUqNqAAemXZtxzG4CAAXtAOFAE0wSXSGbvCHB7i2wWGI1HuzgocVm86zsfpK2EI+l5-VUhv3E4h1F9gWJUlWwAKy-KBINVR5hwQMc60nJdwIA7RATtYEbw7GN72IcDaTiDAQ0yWlcirYBPQQ-DSCXVcoA4RwhWmaBsKjGMKKgYA4C4qZWPbdihQkXBdWBB05TY4B73iYjSLotdGOYvi21vVBuN4-jVKgYScF1cSLB+UYVJwrtcDsHAODAdwdLCNBIh05dJPvMJ6NdNgWOMwSGITQgkwgCoAyOWpThxRwxggDgkCHas-mAMggOBBVpAAQjg6sAH5x3raYwmmc8Q0wCACoAURSElpAAIjSyizQkKAIBwMBQAq2VzFbHTe37Qdqs9UcssnadZ3nUpdVAskkApMATwoiQEr1Mb+Qm1AqS8Wl6SiZlWXZCROTmzDtNwUiZIPUTHT03U3IOnBzMs6RYjsg9lx6-qcoCg5FopYqYF4DEABkAHkADkoQRCBUgANioD7UDGWMAA0AH0MQAFWKgAlEHimKANqmOOooG+OAcB+NkGHCxwEEi6LKNi+LYtLeVFVSp5MqQnLePywqSrK0kqqeWr6sa5rdl1JLnrZqZ0DQDAET23lLp6kc-TEgMyzBYIoVC65bnuGQetUULwqpnqdhxl8xo-NAnzNZVYcRlH0aXACEDl4Foc8mqMGeiyrKmh6MP29gBWtYVuAYCUPGUUJTrlJKVSgL6foBwHXcDy6EWXRO-qBmPeX0u1LscXPyhF4C+WD4IEaQIqoUkmN40TZN9Y92bc6SpYI+CKOq6KsJVSz5PU7lS7K+rkNi9zjWMFHorzoOYER7egMPrgUFazgT5pEJ4ngFJ8nKai4ghhHEoSlIZRj+KU+oFHC+eRPm-VARAo-RybQgA).

Comment: JS syntax question: why are you using a complex test instead of using an ampty array as  default parameter and then testing for length? `function geometricMedian(points = []) { if (!points.length) { throw Error ...`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I transpiled it from TS for Stackoverflow. I actually wrote it as `if(!points?.length) throw new Error("points is empty")` which is nice and short. I don't really want a default, it's a required param.

Comment: Just post the TS instead and mark it typescript? Nothing wrong with showing your _actual_ code?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The issue is that it's not executable within Stackoverflow. Was trying to make it easy. I can post a TS playground link I suppose. Edit: Added the link

Comment: *"This method converges for almost all initial positions, but may fail to converge when one of its estimates falls on one of the given points. It can be modified to handle these cases so that it converges for all initial points."* Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median#Computation

Comment: 1) Your code does not converge, it oscillates between `[0,0,0]` and `[0, 0, 12]` 2) I think the correct version of the algorithm should have the weights as `1/calcDist(p, x)` which also doesn't work if you choose the initial guess as one of the points. 3) It seems OK though if you start with `x = findMean(points);`

Comment: @user3386109 Ah... I missed that bit. "modified" how? With some random jitter?

Comment: @kikon If I do that, then it returns the mean (https://go.mpen.ca/9jdjb), I want it to be one of the points. Maybe if I tweak it a bit further to pick a point at the end (https://go.mpen.ca/9jdjb)...

Comment: No it returns what you expect, if you correct your typo (as per point 2) of my message) https://tsplay.dev/WG4qJw You can apply `findClosest` after the algorithm has computed the correct (up to EPSILON) median, if you want the point closest to the median

Comment: @kikon Your link also gives `[0, 0, 4] ` but doesn't have the `1/` fix in it. With that it gives `[0, 0, 7.152556946721261e-7] ` https://go.mpen.ca/3akau

Comment: Sorry, I failed to save the updated link - I shorted yours. You have it right now. `[0, 0, 7.152556946721261e-7]` is `[0, 0, 0]` with the `EPSILON = 1e-6`. That's the best you can do with this algorithm. I would also advise to change the logic of your loop - if  the `calcDist(x,x_new) < EPSILON` condition was not satisfied, it's most likely an error - i.e., the algorithm did not "converge", as was the case in your first version.

Comment: @kikon Oh right.. darn `e-7` confused me. Yep. That's close enough, Thank you :-D  The `1/calcDist` thing introduces a divide by 0 bug, but that's easy enough to fix https://go.mpen.ca/21mx2

Comment: Right, [here's](https://tsplay.dev/WYRdEw) an updated version that **1)** includes the convergence test I mentioned earlier. **2)** I set a different, stricter condition for division by zero, so you get convergence *before* division by zero if the *exact* solution happens to be one of the points.

Comment: Seems like what you're looking for is the [medoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medoid), which is not the same as the geometric median.

Comment: @kikon You don't need the `converged` bool since it returns immediately after

Comment: @user3386109 I think you are correct! I thought the geometric median would almost always be a point in the set, unless there's an even number of points but even then the 3D version kind of breaks my head. But yes, Medoid would better for what I'm trying to do

Comment: @kikon Yes, but you get the warning without the bool too: https://go.mpen.ca/5sgna

Comment: Oh, yeah - my bad I thought it was a `break` there.